# DNS query format little-big endian problem in header structure

Tags: c++, c, dns

I have a question about DNS query Format ....

I know this structure as the structure of DNS query header ...

```
typedef struct _DNS_HEADER {
    unsigned short id;       // identification number
    unsigned char qr :1;     // query/response flag
    unsigned char opcode :4; // purpose of message
    unsigned char aa :1;     // authoritative answer
    unsigned char tc :1;     // truncated message
    unsigned char rd :1;     // recursion desired
    unsigned char ra :1;     // recursion available
    unsigned char z :1;      // its z! reserved
    unsigned char ad :1;     // authenticated data
    unsigned char cd :1;     // checking disabled
    unsigned char rcode :4;  // response code
    unsigned short q_count;  // number of question entries
    unsigned short ans_count; // number of answer entries
    unsigned short auth_count; // number of authority entries
    unsigned short add_count; // number of resource entries
} DNS_HEADER;
```

+ question query and ...

but there is a problem here:
I created a socket `socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP)` and i created a query request:

```
id = htons(10000);
qr = 0;
opcode = 0
aa = 0
tc = 0
rd = 1
ra = 0
z = 0 
ad = 0
cd = 0
q_count = 1
ans_count = 0
auth_count = 0
add_count = 0
```

and my question ->

```
3,'w','w','w',4,'s','i','t','e',3,'c','o','m',0

TYPE = htons(1)
CLASS = htons(1)
```

I sent this request to my special DNS server (bind) and I think there was a problem. Sometimes DNS server didn't responded me and even on response, it wasn't a true response (everything was 0 and nothing received except same header (12-BYTE))

I searched and I found out that there is a problem with my DNS header and it Must be like this ->

```
typedef struct _DNS_HEADER {
    unsigned short id;       // identification number

    unsigned char rd :1;     // recursion desired
    unsigned char tc :1;     // truncated message
    unsigned char aa :1;     // authoritative answer
    unsigned char opcode :4; // purpose of message
    unsigned char qr :1;     // query/response flag

    unsigned char rcode :4;  // response code
    unsigned char cd :1;     // checking disabled
    unsigned char ad :1;     // authenticated data
    unsigned char z :1;      // its z! reserved
    unsigned char ra :1;     // recursion available

    unsigned short q_count;  // number of question entries
    unsigned short ans_count; // number of answer entries
    unsigned short auth_count; // number of authority entries
    unsigned short add_count; // number of resource entries
} DNS_HEADER;
```

something about little-big endian. I changed my structure to this structure and I sent request and DONE - everything worked and there wasn't any problem, but this is my problem: I don't get it what this is this. Yes, I read about little-big endian a little but still i don't get it:

1. Why haven't other websites that teaches about DNS format mentioned this? They teach with the first structure.
2. What is this? Why we must change the higher 8 bits of the second 16 bits to be the lower 8 bits of the second 16 bits?

Comment: Note that bitfield layout is in no way portable, and you'd better off using an array of unsigned char to map to the packet contents.

Comment: There are usually some ENDIANESS `#ifdef`'s around the bitfields to place them in the correct order. This particular `DNS_HEADER` won't work everywhere as @AnttiHaapala noticed.

Comment: Standard C does not even promise that `unsigned char` can be used as a bitfield type.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Oh ... and I just read "_Multiple adjacent bit fields are **usually** packed together (although this behavior is implementation-defined)_" about C++. I was under the impression that was required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why haven't other websites that teaches about DNS format mentioned this? They teach with the first structure.

I can't possibly answer that. Most networking litterature I've come across mentions network byte order and the motivation for it.

> Why we must change the higher 8 bits of the second 16 bits to be the lower 8 bits of the second 16 bits?

The motivation for it is found in "[IEN-137] Cohen, D., "ON HOLY WARS AND A PLEA FOR PEACE", IEN 137, USC/ISI, April 1980." that is referred to in a Internet Engineering Task Force draft: [Network Byte Order](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-newman-network-byte-order-01)

> Background and Motivation
>
> > The document "ON HOLY WARS AND A PLEA FOR PEACE" `[IEN-137]` written
> > in 1980 argues that the industry should settle on a single byte
> > order.  Since then, the IETF has largely settled on a single byte
> > order known as "Network Byte Order" and this memo is intended to
> > record that rough concensus.  Unfortunately, **the "holy war"
> > continues among CPU manufacturers**.

The last sentence is what this comes down to.

Some CPU models use [Big-Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and others use Little-Endian. There are even those using a mix.

Two bytes (in binary form) representing a `std::uint16_t`:

Big-Endian: `10000000 00000000` means ‭32768‬ (decimal).
Little-Endian: `10000000 00000000` means ‭128 (decimal).

If there was no agreement on how to interpret these two bytes, communication would be very hard.

Comment: This actually is not a full answer.  OP's structure that didn't work used the order `AA`,`TC`,`RD`, whereas the structure that did work ordered these `RD`,`TC`,`AA`.  **These three bits are in the same byte**, meaning that not only are the *bytes* reversed, but the *bits* are reversed also.  Big vs. little endian is normally about the **byte** order, not the bit order; ie, `0xABCD` vs `0xCDAB`, but `AB` and `CD` themselves are the same on either big- or little-endian machines.  Thus there is also a separate issue of the compiler's interpretation of bit fields.

Comment: @Kevin That's true. For struct definitions with bit fields that are targeted fo be used by different implementations one will usually find some `#ifdef`s that places the bitfields in different order so the resulting data will be properly packaged. Looking at the [DNS HEADER](https://pastebin.com/TrhLjRWQ) layout, one would think that OP:s original `struct` definition would work, but it did not in that implementation because it packages the bit fields from LSb to MSb, which I assume is common in little endian environments.